# Android Services and Android LifeCycle handling

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle

I have created an app where I use two activities such that:

1st Activity is Main Activity, &
2nd Activity starts from Main Activity using a Button.

Now I have started a sound(using service) in Main activity and want to keep that service alive as long as my app is alive but want to stop is if it app closes(by either pressing back button or Home button).

The problem is that when I use onPause/onResume methods then sound service stops when I start 2nd Activity.

Anyone having any idea how to tackle it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi There, Please check the logic in onpause and onResume i think ur stoping the service in onPause and starting that service in on Resume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `onResume()` and `onPause()`, use `onUserLeaveHint()`.
When you call the other Activity add this to your `Intent`:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
```

You can read more about it here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint%28%29

Answer (score 0):

override onBackPressed() in your mainactivity and stop the service here

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

for home button press see the following link

http://nisha113a5.blogspot.in/